# If two conditions is value 1 - do something

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm having trouble with if-statements for javascript.
It doesn't recognize if there are two conditions that are equal to 1

I have this code:

```
   if(variable=1 && another=1) {
   //do something
   }
```

What is the issue?

Comment: `=` assigns. Use `==` or `===`.

Comment: `variable=value` will **always** return `true` as the variable was - indeed - set.

Comment: By the way why does this not work at all ? I mean `if (true && true)` seems to work - http://jsfiddle.net/6ke5N/ :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(variable==1 && another==1) {
   //do something
   }
```

two equals signs for comparison, one equal sign for assignment

As @Johan says: === to compare types!!!

Don't mess with the Johan :)

Comment: And three to compare the type in a loosely typed language like JS ;)

Answer (score 0):

In `if()` condition you are assinging values by `=`

It is wrong,

you should compare it by using `==`

```
   if(variable == 1 && another == 1) {
     //do something
   }
```